# strtok gives me only the first slice

Tags: c, string, strtok

This is my first project written in C and I'm trying to split a C-string into "words".

The following lines are for testing and work fine:

```
Serial.println("SliceTest2");
  char *ptr;
  char delimiter[] = " ,";
  ptr = strtok(packetBuffer, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
  Serial.println(ptr);
```

With packetBuffer containing "a b c d e f g h" this is the output (which is correct):

```
SliceTest2
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Now, when I'm using the following lines:

```
char *sliceStr(char fullString[]){
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strtok(packetBuffer, " ");
  ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n\t ");
  return("%s", ptr);
}
```

and call them (agin with the same contents in packetBuffer "a b c d e f g h"):

```
Serial.println(sliceStr(packetBuffer));
```

it SHOULD print

```
b
```

but does nothing.

It's an arduino project btw, but a C-specific problem.

lg, couka

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char *sliceStr(char *packetBuffer){`?

Comment: `ptr = strtok(packetBuffer, " ");` -->> `ptr = strtok(fullString, " ");`

Comment: By the way, I don't think `return("%s", ptr);` works like how you think it works.

Comment: `return("%s", ptr);` - what is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is not pure C. Serial.println("foo"); it's a method of a class. Probably you are programing on Arduino or similar in a C/C++ derived language.

`printf("%s", ptr);` will substitute the `%s` with string at address `ptr` - but only because it is a function

return is a keyword which is returning a value, in this case you want the pointer `ptr`

`return("%s", ptr);` does not make sense in C.

also note: the `char*` pointer returned must point inside a valid c-string, such as one declared before calling the function. beware do not return pointers to variable declared inside the function as they are local and disappear when function ends.

long story short, try: `return ptr;`

if it doesn't work and need further help please specify the exactly what language and platform are you using

**Edit:** 
`return("%s", ptr);` is wrong but will still work.

However you used global variable `packetBuffer` when the parameter you wanted to tokenize was in fact `fullString`

This sample code will work and print `b` as you expect.
I used in the example an allocated copy of the argument because `strtok` needs writable memory to put temporary zeros (end of string) during tokenizing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *sliceStr(char *packetBuffer){
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strtok(packetBuffer, " ");
  ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n\t ");
  return("%s", ptr);
}

int main() {
    char *str = strdup("a b c d etc");
    printf("%s\n", sliceStr(str));
}
```

Comment: `return("%s", ptr)` is valid C code. But it is true that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Andrey T is right. In `c`, the statement `"%s", ptr` is valid and evaluated from left to right with the rightmost value being the return value of the whole statement. Therefore the statement `return("%s", ptr)` will return whatever `ptr` evaluates to.

Comment: `Serial.println("foo");` is valid C, too, if `Serial` is the name of a `struct` with a pointer-to-function member called `println`.

Comment: I appreciate all the pedantics here, though I don't see how they help on the topic. As the OP stated he is a beginner, I doubt his intention was to launch an obfuscated C blitz.

Comment: I don't see how incorrectly telling him in your answer he's not programming in C is all that much more helpful. If you don't think he cares about it, why bring those things up at all?

Comment: Totally different. A clean code in the language of your choice will have you find the error easier. Obfuscated code will make it harder. I was merely trying to understand what's wrong and what's not and to close in to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advices.

Mixing up `packetBuffer` and `fullString` was dumb, but didn't cause the problem since until now it always had the same content.

`return("%s", ptr)` isn't the finished line and makes no sense as it is, but no problems here.

I have not managed to get it to work with pure C, so I will use C++ and its `String`-class from now. Didn't want to, but ok...

Anyway, the Problem seems to be the line `ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");`.

```
 ptr = strtok(fullString, " ");
```

gives me the first word as intended, but repeating it with `NULL` never works.

lg, couka

Comment: Dude copy/paste the code in my answer and compile it and run it you'll see it works I tested it myself.

Comment: I understand you fixed your code but I don't know how. Depending where that buffer comes and the relationships between your function and external variables there can be many side-effects. If you insist your code is correct but it is not working just paste here the whole source, I'll have a look.